# Gitlab-ci installed and running as a root

Tags: linux, centos, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've installed gitlab-ci using manual of the gitlab-ci site on centos 6.7, for some reason everytime my computer has a reboot the process is being run from root using gitlab-runner user.

And every time I kill the process and launch it back from my local user,
Is there a way to cause the process to run on local user instead of root permanently , where can I change that?

When doing `ps -ef |grep gitlab` you get the following:

`/usr/bin/gitlab-ci-multi-runner run --working-directory /home/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --user gitlab-runner`

Thanks